# Uneven tire tread causing worrisome traction problems - wlll this fix it?

Tags: tires, bmw, traction-control

I'm running a set of staggered run-flat `Goodyear Eagle F1 Asymmetric 2's` on my RWD. Fronts are 225/40//19, rears are 255/35/19.

I've been driving with the passenger rear tire much newer than the rest of the tires, thus notably more tread. This, however, hasn't produced any super noticeable traction issues.

However, my passenger front tire recently had to be replaced. So now, both passenger tires have notably more tread than the drivers side tires. This has caused a surprisingly unsafe feeling whenever I gun it from a slower speed. The car sways side to side, at times to the point where it almost feels like I'll lose control.

These run-flats are expensive. I almost got some `Michelin PS4S's` but I like the idea of run-flats and as far as run-flats go, these are among the best. I don't want to buy a whole new set - **do you think moving one of the new tires diagonal to the other new tire may help counter this?** AKA, if I move the new passenger front tire to the front drivers side, so that it's diagonal with the newer rear passenger tire - might that help a bit?

It makes sense in my head but I really have no idea if it's a valid strategy. Obviously new tires would be ideal but at that point I think I'd just get a new set of PS4S.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

While you can move it, I don't recommend doing so. The reason is, some would say there may be an issue with the tires already having a set drive pattern in them. Moving the tires to the opposite side could cause there to be a wear issue in the future.

One thing which might be going on is if you are experiencing lower temperatures (near freezing or getting much colder), these tires are for summer use only. Per [TireRack.com](https://www.tirerack.com/tires/tires.jsp?tireMake=Goodyear&tireModel=Eagle+F1+Asymmetric+2+RunOnFlat):

> ... Max Performance Summer run-flat tires **are not intended to be driven in near-freezing temperatures**, through snow or on ice.

If it is cold where you're at, the tire may not be keeping up with it, and thus causing your stability issues.

From the same page, GoodYear also gives this warning:

> Goodyear's warranty states: "Ultra high-performance summer tires are not recommended for winter use, and tread or shoulder cracking on those tires resulting from winter use will not be covered under our warranty."

One other thing of note ... these aren't typical "run-flat" tires. They are called "run-on-flat" tires, which don't have the full longevity of typical run-flats. According to the TireRack page, it states:

> Though they cannot be labeled as run-flat tires, tires branded with MOExtended or MOE on their sidewalls offer run-flat-like characteristics by delivering limited temporary extended mobility after a puncture results in complete loss of air pressure. Because MOExtended or MOE tires do not have the same speed and distance endurance of conventional run-flat tires, they should not be substituted in any situation where a conventional run-flat tire is required.